# ReactJS - Custom hook return function doesn't store actual data from internal state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook `useNotifications` for Notification widget. This hook returns an array with the next elements (it's similar to ant.design message api):

- `add`: function to add a new notification
- `remove`: function which gets a notification id and removes the notification
- `contextHandler`: JSX which is passed into component's render

When user calls `add` they get an id which can be used to remove the notification

The problem is dedicated to remove function particularly. Since I call this function right after I add new notification, the function receives a copy of old list so there's no new element and it throws an error. How can I fix it so there's same API for the Component uses that?

[useNotification hook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ2GC.png)
[How I use it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC7c4.png)

Codesandbox (for test I did `setTimeout` which calls `remove()` in 3 seconds): https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-smoke-5q7dw3?file=/src/App.js:405-440

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your `remove` function use the [state updater function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) which has access to the most up-to-date state value. This allows you to access the new `list` state before your component has rerendered within `remove()`.

Note: You're currently mutating your original state by setting the nested object's `isMounted` property to `false`. Even though you make a copy of your array, you should also make a copy of the object you're updating to avoid rerendering issues.

Below are some modifications on how you can access the most up-to-date value of your state and avoid state mutations:

```js
const add = useCallback((params) => {
  const id = v4();
  const element = {...params, id, isMounted: true};
  setList(list => [...list, element]); // Add your new element while also making a copy of the current state (`list`)
  return id;
}, []);

const remove = useCallback((elementId) => {
  setList((list) =>
    list.map((elem) => elem.id === elementId 
      ? { ...elem, isMounted: false } 
      : elem
    )
  );
  setTimeout(() => {
    setList((list) => list.filter((elem) => elem.id !== elementId));
  }, 500);
}, []);
```

See example below:

[image: Edit withered-bush-cgr4q6]